# Exception in JMenu

Tags: java, swing, jmenu

I've developed an application in Java..

The problem occuring with it is that after first click, if the user clicks on menu again then following exception occurs..

Since it is showing that source is unknown, it is not possible for me to debug it...

Can anyone help me with this ??

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics$MetricsKey.init(Unknown Source)
        at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(Unknown Source)
        at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(Unknown Source)
        at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuItemUI.paint(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuUI.paint(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthMenuUI.update(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You've shown **zero** code, but I can tell you that a [`NullPointerException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) occurs when you try to deference an object which is `null`.

Comment: You have a problem with the code in your ActionListener for the Menu. Post a SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The code on clicking on menu item calls JFileChooser and selects appropritate file name.. If filename is not null then calls a function for further processing.. and even I agree with Matt's argument. But I'm just trying to figure out what is null ..

Comment: but without code, all we can say is "well, good luck with that".

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that the first click is the one that displays the menu and the menu items.  If the user then clicks on a menu item, and you get an exception, I would bet that you have not fully instantiated some of the menu item components associated with the menu.

Hope this helps.

John Doner

Comment: nopes .. on first click to menu item it shows expected result..
Second time, click on any menu option throws above exception...

Answer (score 0):

```
 at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics$MetricsKey.init(Unknown Source)
```

Check the instantiation of your fonts. You need to use `new Font(name, ...)` somewhere.